# Find the upper bound or lower bound of the specific number in Redis

Tags: redis

For example,I have a set in Redis

`5 7 11 15 19 2 1`

I want to find the upper bound or lower bound of `12` in Redis.
They are `15` and `11` in this example.

How can I do it efficiently.

I can use `set` or `ordered set`

Thanks!

Comment: so that I understand, you are wanting two numbers, the next higher and next lower than `12`?

Comment: yes :)  @NappingRabbit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways, neither of them perfect.

if they are all in a `set`, you can check (`$r->sIsMember()`) for that number `12` and then iteratively walk up and down until a match is found for each.  This is **not** great, and I would suggest a `LUA` script to avoid a ton `back-and-forth` if you go that route.

second, put them in a `sorted set` as scores to a primary key of sorts.  Then you will `zRangeByScore()` and get the `zRank()` of that member of the sorted set, and then `zRange()` to get the value before and after.  I will do that here:

add them to a sorted set:

```
zadd mysset 5 "one"
zadd mysset 7 "two"
zadd mysset 11 "three"
zadd mysset 15 "four"
zadd mysset 19 "five"
zadd mysset 2 "six"
zadd mysset 1 "seven"
```

add one on the fly for reference

```
zadd mysset 12 "center"
```

now get the rank of that `reference`:

```
zRank mysset "center"    
// 6 in this case
```

now get the range of the one above and below `withscores`:

```
zRange mysset 7 7 WITHSCORES
zRange mysset 5 5 WITHSCORES
// "four" 15
// "three" 11
```

good luck, have fun!

**edit:** oh yeh, remove the reference number:

```
zrem mysset "center"
```

Comment: Thanks! My idea is the second. I put a number in sorted set. Both of the key and score is the number. Like this `zadd mysset 5 "5"`.  Thanks for your help! Thanks a lot!